# How to make video grid on ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, video

i am trying to make the video divide into 2 or 4 segments and each segment have a video that different from other segments.

[image: pic]
i 've tried openshot, but there is no such feature i can use to make it done.
Any ideas how I can do this?